# Should the help section have a PGN viewer tutorial?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, pgn-viewer

I would like to suggest that the help section should have a tutorial on putting a PGN viewer in a post - question or answer. I have mainly come from mathematics where the use of mathematical typesetting is a regular issue for new users. Well directed help gets new users on board.

A help tutorial could indicate site protocols and also provide links to some of the material already here on Meta.

It took quite a while to find out how to do get a chess board/game in a post (and PGN viewer wasn't the first search term which came to mind - my first question was how to include a chess board in a post).

This is my third attempt to get going on the site - and this has been my issue every time. I think I may have cracked it, but it wasn't obvious, and that may be putting other people off. Hence this suggestion.

---

Another thing I looked for as a newbie was a short-cut for adding a game board to a post (like the ones for adding a picture or a link). That could also be worth doing.

Comment: There are two FAQ posts about it on Meta: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-does-the-sites-new-pgn-viewer-work and http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post

Answer (score 6):

Yes I agree, feel free to post a tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

Only [very specific parts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/295232) of the Help Center can be edited by ♦ moderators, and Stack Exchange staff usually doesn't make exceptions. Almost all pages are used network-wide.

That said, user @SteveBennett (almost the same last name!) rekindled this topic [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/991/7297) and IMHO, given the available options, the [main Help Center page](/help) is the best place, so I've added a link to the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! (Btw I'd consider trying to stick the words PGN or FEN in that line, since that's what people would often be skimming for.)

Comment: Thanks, certainly doesn't hurt to add those.