# Documentation for embedding a game?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I cannot find any information how to embed a position anywhere in the help centre.  Here would be a really obvious place for it to be: https://chess.stackexchange.com/editing-help

The only way I can figure out how to do it is to find an existing question with an embedded game, then view the source, and do the same thing.

Is it possible to get some basic documentation added to the help centre? Or even to the UI when you're asking a question?

Comment: We can't change the editing help page, as it's a network wide thing.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is a duplicate. My question is: is there *anything* that can be done to make improve the documentation situation? At the moment it's basically impossible to find anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's nothing we can change here. I've found another old thread which basically asks for the same.

Comment: There's no ability change any of the content anywhere in the Help Center? Even to add a few links to that thread?

Comment: Very limited (see the bottom paragraphs of [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153/295232)). Actually, it might make sense to add it to /help, let me try something ...